# The application of the textures to the body changed the eye colors of my model

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to apply the textures to my model using the `projection paint` tecnique explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J32ptRl-b9A).

I've been able to apply the textures to the bird's body,but then the eyes stopped working. Infact,before to apply the textures,the eyes look ok,but after,they look dark grey. I don't understand what happened. This is how they look before :

[image]

and after :

[image]

I attached the blender file :

[image]

thanks.

Comment: There are no texture in the .blend file. Before you upload it, you should go to _File > External Data_ and check _Automatically Pack Into .blend_.

Comment: You also haven't assigned a material to the eyes, so they're showing white in texture mode.

Comment: Hello. I have packed the textures inside the blend file and I reuploaded it. But I haven't been able to understand how to assign a material to the eyes,also because I think that it has been assigned already !